# Color Animation ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, animation, colors, contentpresenter, visualstates

I can't create an animation, or customize a color in ContentPresenter (NormalTextDay), this error appears in my XAML:

'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation' animation object can not be used to animate property 'Foreground' it is because of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush

```
  <Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <!--<Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                </Storyboard>-->
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CalendarButtonFocusStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Active"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Inactive">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalTextDay"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="GridValues"/>
                                    <!--<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalTextDay">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFA71616"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->

                                    <!--<ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF777777" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalTextDay"/>-->
                                </Storyboard>

                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RegularDay"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Today">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalTextDay"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BlackoutDayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalDay"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BlackoutDay">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Blackout"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground" Fill="#FFAAAAAA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground" Fill="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground" Fill="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalTextDay" TextBlock.Foreground="#FF333333" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.Row="0">
                    </ContentPresenter>

                        <Path x:Name="Blackout" Data="M8.1772461,11.029181 L10.433105,11.029181 L11.700684,12.801641 L12.973633,11.029181 L15.191895,11.029181 L12.844727,13.999395 L15.21875,17.060919 L12.962891,17.060919 L11.673828,15.256231 L10.352539,17.060919 L8.1396484,17.060919 L10.519043,14.042364 z" Fill="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DayButtonFocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="false" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF45D6FA" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <DataGrid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="GridValues" Grid.Row="1">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Período" Width="*" MaxWidth="200"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Nº Max." Width="Auto" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: On my PC it looks like a problem of visual studio designer. You should be able to run the program or to render the XAML code correctly in Expression Blend

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not quite sure... but you might need to change this:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
```

to this:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).Color"
```

as in this syntax "Foreground" and "SolidColorBrush" are the same object you seem to be duplicating it.

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  I created a copy of the CalendarDayButtonStyle using blend for vs2012, then found that vs2010 couldn't view the style without the exception above being thrown.