# IntegerUpDown Control Changing Background When Textbox IsFocused

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, styles

I'm creating a WPF application and am using the WPF Extended Toolkit library  . I have added the IntegerUpDown control to my UserControl and when the user presses inside the textbox I want the background color to change from a dark grey to a light grey.

I have tried adding a style trigger in the xaml that triggers when the IntegerUpDown control IsFocused for the background to change. However, this did not seem to work.

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="Day" Value="{Binding DayText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource IntegerUpDownStyle}" Minimum="{Binding MinimumDateSelection}" Maximum="{Binding MaximumDateSelection}">
                            <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Watermark>
                                <TextBlock Text="Day" Foreground="{StaticResource OffsetWhiteBrush}" Margin="0,0,60,0"/>
                            </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Watermark>
                        </xctk:IntegerUpDown>




<!-- Textbox and PasswordBox base styling for login boxes -->
    <Style x:Key="IntegerUpDownStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextStyle}">
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="400" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSize20}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkGreyBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGreyBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

With the styling I've added I expected the background of the control to change from a dark grey to a light grey but nothing happened. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this problem in my own app,and it's finished.Here's code:

```
<Window
x:Class="WpfApp16.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp16"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="800"
Height="450"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="IntegerUpDownStyle" TargetType="xctk:IntegerUpDown">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ValueChanged">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                From="DarkGray"
                                To="Transparent"
                                Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>

            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>

    <xctk:IntegerUpDown Width="200" Style="{StaticResource IntegerUpDownStyle}">
        <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
        </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Background>
    </xctk:IntegerUpDown>
</StackPanel>
```

For more Information ,look this linke:[WPF Animation dependency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811030/wpf-animation-dependency-issue)

Answer (score 0):

The same trigger in IntegerUpDown source code, so the outside trigger was no longer effective.

[IntegerUpDown source code:](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml)

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox"
          Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
          Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" />
</Trigger>
```

I tried using GotFocus and LostFocus events.

xaml:

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="Day" 
     LostFocus="IntegerUpDown_LostFocus" 
     GotFocus="IntegerUpDown_GotFocus"  
     Focusable="True"  
     Value="{Binding DayText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource IntegerUpDownStyle}" Minimum="{Binding MinimumDateSelection}" Maximum="{Binding MaximumDateSelection}">
   <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Watermark>
        <TextBlock Text="Day" Foreground="{StaticResource OffsetWhiteBrush}" Margin="0,0,60,0"/>
    </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Watermark>
</xctk:IntegerUpDown>
```

cs code:

```
private void IntegerUpDown_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Day.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
}

private void IntegerUpDown_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Day.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the answer from @J.B.D I edited the ControlTemplate for the IntegerUpDown control to change the back

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <xctk:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner" AllowSpin="{Binding AllowSpin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ButtonSpinnerLocation="{Binding ButtonSpinnerLocation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" ShowButtonSpinner="{Binding ShowButtonSpinner, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" AutoMoveFocus="{Binding AutoMoveFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" AutoSelectBehavior="{Binding AutoSelectBehavior, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" AcceptsReturn="False" BorderThickness="0" ContextMenu="{TemplateBinding ContextMenu}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="True" IsUndoEnabled="True" MinWidth="20" MaxLength="{Binding MaxLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextAlignment="{Binding TextAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" WatermarkTemplate="{Binding WatermarkTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Watermark="{Binding Watermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkGreyBrush}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGreyBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
                </xctk:WatermarkTextBox>

            </xctk:ButtonSpinner>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlMouseOverBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding AllowTextInput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlSelectedBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Please look at the start of the control template and the WatermarkTextBox. The WatermarkTextBox.Style is what I added to make the background change when the textbox is focused.

**To override the COntrolTemplate, right click on the IntegerUpDown Control and then press Edit Template**